# Initializing string error "The value is not available in the current context"?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm pretty new in programming and currently I'm doing my first tries in c# in combination with XAML.

One tutorial project I picked for practice reasons is an application which simply creates, updates and deletes users from a sql database. Now i have one issue with the initialisation of a string (basically the connection string for the creation of the db connection). The issue is that i'm not able to split up the declaration and the initialisation of the string variable which contains the connection string.

When I do it like this:

```
namespace UserManagement
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static string conString;
        conString = @"XXXXXX"; 
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(conString);
```

I get the error message for the initialisation of "conString" with the value: "The value "conString" is not available in the current context" (VisualStudio 2019)

Whereas when I do it like this it works fine:

```
namespace UserManagement
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static string conString = @"XXXXXX";
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(conString);
```

So the difference is only that when split up declaration and initialisation it does not work but when I do it in once it works.

It is not really a problem because I know how to get it working but I would like to understand the behaviour.

Can maybe somebody help me with this?

Thank you in advance for your support.

Best regards

EnSe

Comment: I think this is a definitely valid question; I don't see this error message dealt with in any other question here (at least any that have the same root problem).

Comment: @EnSe, can you please give any feedback to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

this is a declaration of a *field* in MainWindow class with initial value @"XXXXXX":

```
public static string conString = @"XXXXXX";
```

this is a declaration of a *field* in MainWindow class without initial value:

```
public static string conString;
```

Both are valid in c#

However, `conString = @"XXXXXX";` is an assignment which cannot be done on class level, it should be inside method, e.g. constructor:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        conString = @"XXXXXX"; 
        cnn = new SqlConnection(conString);
    }

    public static string conString;
    SqlConnection cnn;
}
```

Comment: [C# fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) (especially the part about field initializers).